# "GET" request working in Python but doesn't work in Robot Framework

Tags: python, rest, python-requests, robotframework

I have the following python method which is part of a Library that is imported into a Robot Framework test suite:

```
    def check_activation_status(self):
        '''
        A simple keyword to check if my app has been activated not. Returns boolean value from the API response.  
                *Arguments*
        '''

        url = os.path.join(self.url, "api/activation")
        print_to_log(url)     # a custom keyword that prints the url to the RF log.html file, just for info purpose
        r = requests.get(url, verify=False)
        activated = r.json()["activated"]
        return activated
```

I am getting the following error when Check Activation Status keyword is called:

```
15:45:11.446    DEBUG   Starting new HTTPS connection (1): localhost:8001   
15:45:11.448    FAIL    ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=8001): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/activation (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7efdcb718a30>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))
```

1. I am not sure why it is "starting a new HTTPS connection" because `https://localhost:8001` is successfully running after the suite setup and this is a follow up check that the tests need to do at the `/api/activation` endpoint.
2. When I run the following in a Python console it works fine and gives me the json value that I expect (True or False)

```
import requests

r = requests.get("https://localhost:8001/api/activation", verify=False)
activated = r.json()['activated']
```

Is there any reason why this works in Python and not in Robot Framework?

I am familiar with the Robot Framework Requests library however, this method of importing my own library allows for readable keywords that are stored in a Python library - and can also be used outside of Robot Framework.

Comment: Share the robot file. I believe you open the HTTPS connection with a different instance and the one in the Python file does not have an open connection.

Comment: What's the value of `self.url`, e.g. the output of `print_to_log(url)`? And don't use `os.path.join()` to construct URLs, that'll fail terribly on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Use the RequestLibrray in robot framework. you can directly use GET method.
[Refer the library here](https://marketsquare.github.io/robotframework-requests/doc/RequestsLibrary.html#:%7E:text=Introduction,well%20known%20Python%20Requests%20Library.)

[pip install robotframework-requests](https://pypi.org/project/robotframework-requests/)

Robot framework library is a python library itself and can be imported inside python file directly- It is not restricted to robot framework. You can use robot framework request library directly into the python file.

Comment: Let me know your findings, ill help you further